# Single Crossfilter Dimension and Group on two columns?

Tags: javascript, crossfilter

I have the following CSV:

```
ccgcode,ccgname,metric,male,female
06M,Great Yarmouth And Waveney,3,24,76
05G,North Staffordshire,3,46,54
... etc.
```

How do I get about creating a `Sex` dimension to drive a `dc.pieChart()`? My question is specifically about the `Dimension` and `Group` aspect of Crossfilter, and not how to render the pie chart.

Comment: You really ought to transform your data so that it is in a more Crossfilter-friendly format. You should change it to have a "Sex" dimension that has values "M" or "F", for example, and then you should have a "Count" dimension with the value.

Comment: So have more granular data. Is that the only way?

Comment: The granularity is the same as the amount of information in the data doesn't change. It's the format that is different. It's not the only way, but it's the best way. Keeping them in separate columns is going to cause you all kinds of problems, while the fairly minimal problems caused by making your data longer rather than wider are already addressed by helper libraries like Reductio and Universe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Crossfilter can't simply sum up the two columns you need so reformatting the data is your best bet (as per the conversation in the comments). You can use [melt.js](https://github.com/jrideout/melt.js), which works like [reshape](http://www.statmethods.net/management/reshape.html) if you're familiar with R, so you don't have touch your raw data.

This solution assumes your data is a list of objects with key-value pairs (pretty standard):

```
data = [
  { ccgcode: '06M', ccgname: 'Great Yarmouth And Waveney', metric: 3, male: 24, female: 76 },
  { ccgcode: '05G', ccgname: 'North Staffordshire', metric: 3, male: 46, female: 54 },
...];
```

You first want to identify all the static columns you don't want to "melt" (disaggregate):

```
var staticColumns = ['ccgcode', 'ccgname', 'metric'];
```

Then you use `melt` to ungroup male and female columns. `Melt` takes in your data, the columns you don't want to melt, and the name of the new melt column (in your case it's `sex`):

```
var ndx = crossfilter(melt(data, staticColumns, 'sex', 'count'));
var sexDim  = ndx.dimension(function (d) { return d.sex; });
```

You end up with the following dimension:

```
sexDim = [
  { sex: 'male', count: 24, _id: 0, ccgcode: '06M', ccgname: 'Great Yarmouth And Waveney', metric: 3 },
  { sex: 'male', count: 46, _id: 1, ccgcode: '05G', ccgname: 'North Staffordshire', metric: 3},
  { sex: 'female', count: 76, _id: 0, ccgcode: '06M', ccgname: 'Great Yarmouth And Waveney', metric: 3 },
  { sex: 'female', count: 54, _id: 1, ccgcode: '05G', ccgname: 'North Staffordshire', metric: 3},
...];
```

Note the helpful `_id` that `melt` creates for you in case you need to tie everything back together (although your static columns help with this too). You can pass `false` as the fifth parameter to `melt` to exclude the `_id` property.

And you can still group by sex:

```
var males = sexDim.group().reduceSum(function (d) {
  if (d.sex === 'male') {
    return d.count;
  } else {
    return 0;
  }
});
```

Hope that helps!